# Laptop ignoring scancode map

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry

My keyboard is messed up, the 'i' and 'o' keys don't work. I'm currently making do with alt+numpad ascii... but it's incredibly annoying (still less than the damn on screen keyboard).

Figured I'd swap some keys around so I could get my vowels back.

I've changed the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout registry file Scancode Map with the following binary [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omI63.png).

However, it had no effect whatsoever. My '+' and '«' keys are still working as such, and I'm going crazy. Bright side is, I now know h♂w t♂ make gender f♀gures! ♥♥♥

Comment: Have you tried a spare (USB( keyboard?

Comment: I only have PS2 ones >.<. :/

Comment: So did you try a different PS2 keyboard?

Comment: Have you cleaned your keyboard?

Comment: You can get a PS2 > USB adapter.

Comment: I know I can get a new keyboard. I just wanted to swap the keys in the registry since I don't want to carry a keyboard wherever I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries have the codes in reverse order. Try this, instead.

```
00 00  00 00    header version
00 00  00 00    header flags
03 00  00 00    number of entries in the map
17 00  0D 00    '+' -> 'I' (0x0D -> 0x17)
18 00  1A 00    '[' -> 'O' (0x1A -> 0x18)
00 00  00 00    null entry for terminator
```

Comment: This worked :) 
Not sure why every website had this reversed. Even SharpKeys has the 'From and To' columns switched, it seems.

Comment: @Fuujin One common use case is swapping the CAPS and Ctrl keys, and the order doesn't matter in that case. Plus, the MS reference page [Keyboard and mouse class drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128267.aspx) has the order wrong as well.